# Update datetime in Database

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
var datetime = DateTime.Now;        
var instantMessage = InstantMassageingManager.GetConverationMessages().FirstOrDefault();
InstantMassageingManager.UpdateConversationMessageReadDateTime(instantMessage.InstantMessageInstanceId, datetime);
var message = InstantMassageingManager.GetMessageById(instantMessage.InstantMessageInstanceId);
Assert.IsTrue(message.ReadDateTime.Value == datetime);
```

in the first line I get `DateTime.Now`

[image]

then I update a record in database: `UpdateConversationMessageReadDateTime`

and get the message again from the database:

[image]

Both `message.ReadDateTime` and `datetime` has same value but with different Tick.

So my test doesn't pass.

Why do I get different values for tick?

Comment: ***WHAT DATABASE*** are you using (and what version), and what **datatype** does your column have in the database table?

Answer (score 7):

I strongly suspect that the type you're using in the database doesn't have the same level of precision - I suspect it's only accurate to the millisecond.

If you want to round-trip the time, you should truncate your "input" time to the nearest millisecond too. For example:

```
TimeSpan rounded = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(original.Ticks / 10000);
```

Or for a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime rounded = new DateTime(original.Year, original.Month, original.Day,
    original.Hour, original.Minute, original.Second, original.Millisecond,
    original.Kind);
```

You should also consider whether you really want to take the *local* time (which depends on the system time zone) or a UTC value. It depends on the context, but it's more frequently appropriate to store UTC values for timestamps, which is what it looks like you've got here.

Comment: Just to add: it might also be worth using the db server's clock rather than the app-server's clock (things like `GETUTCDATE()` in t-sql, for example)